# Need to highlight array if condition is met. But How?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, formatting, range

I have a cell with  data to filter with specific text (pre-filtered). just want to highlight  specific cells with the cell value that meet the array of special cells.

```
Sub EmailDataPrep()

    Dim r As Range 
    Dim lastrow As Long 
    Dim MyArray() As Variant
    
    MyArray = Range("F3:F200")
    
    currow = Sheets("Current_Emails").Range("F3")
    
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F3").End(xlUp).row
    
    For Each r In Range("F" & currow & "F" & lastrow)
    
        If r.Value = MyArray Then
    
            r.Interior.Color = "Green"
    
        End If
  
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your code doing that is in error?

Comment: *Lots* of issues in your code. `MyArray = Range("F3.F200")` will fail, should be `:` instead of `.` `currow = Range("F3")` is implicitly referencing the `ActiveSheet`. `.MyArray` makes no sense, why the period? 
`Cells.Interior.Color = "Green"` is all cells. Missing `End If`. You can't compare a single cell's value to an array. You need a loop or `Application.Match`, which is slow when used with arrays.

Comment: it is giving an error as next with our r.

Comment: i have amended to codes now as below.

Comment: `vbGreen`, not `"Green"`.

Comment: Missing `End If`.

Comment: `If r.Value = MyArray Then` is invalid. You can't compare a single cell to an array directly like that.

Comment: `Range("F" & currow & "F" & lastrow)` should be `Range("F" & currow & ":F" & lastrow)`

Comment: and use: `If Not Iserror(application.Match(r.Value,MyArray,0)) Then`

Comment: `Cells(Rows.Count, "F3")` should be `Cells(Rows.Count, "F")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Highlight Matching Cells

- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- It is assumed that there are two worksheets in the workbook containing this code.
- The values of the `Source Column Range` will be written to an array. A loop through the cells of the `Destination (Column) Range`, will attempt to match each cell value against the array. If a match is found, the reference to the current cell will be combined in the `Combined Range`. Finally, all (matching) cells of the `Combined Range`  will be highlighted.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub EmailDataPrep()

    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1" '***
    Const sFirst As String = "F3"
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Current_Emails"
    Const dFirst As String = "F3"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define Source Range and write its values to Data Array.
    Dim srg As Range
    With wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirst)
        Dim sCell As Range
        Set sCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If sCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set srg = .Resize(sCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    
    ' Define Destination Range.
    Dim drg As Range
    With wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirst)
        Dim dCell As Range
        Set dCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If dCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set drg = .Resize(dCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    ' Loop through cells of Destination Range and attempt to find
    ' a match in Data Array. If found, combine its reference to the matching cell
    ' in the Combined Range.
    Dim crg As Range
    For Each dCell In drg.Cells
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(dCell.Value, Data, 0)) Then
            If crg Is Nothing Then
                Set crg = dCell
            Else
                Set crg = Union(crg, dCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next dCell
    
    ' Highlight matching cells (cells of the Combined Range) in one go.
    If Not crg Is Nothing Then
        crg.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    End If
    
End Sub
```